# Moving a point along a curve in matlab

Tags: matlab, graphics, graph, curve

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Points moving along a curve within MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687437/points-moving-along-a-curve-within-matlab)

I have two arrays ,the first represents the x-axis values and the second represents the y-axis values of a certain curve. I want to draw a point (or some object) that moves along that curve in MATLAB.

Comment: i found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687437/points-moving-along-a-curve-within-matlab

Answer (score 1):

You can just trace the curve, i.e., you can place the cyrsor on the curve and press left or right to move your cursor across it.