# Creating a point moving along a graph in MATLAB animation

Tags: matlab, animation, point

I am looking to create 2 dots which move along 2 graphs within MATLAB in which the model shows the point moving along the curve with time. I know there has been ask a similar question here, but it doesn't help me that much :-( I already tried to implement this solution: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959528/creating-a-point-moving-along-a-graph-in-matlab)
I do not know how to implement the

```
b = linspace(x1,10,numPoints);
```

into my solution.

[image: the 2 graphs]

**Here is my code of the 2 graphs:**

```
%% definitions

% initial velocity is assumed to be zero
g = -9.81; % [m/s^2]
m = 1; % [kg]
v = -10; % velocity [m/s]
x = [0:10];

t = [0:0.01:2]; % Vector with 10 Elements, step size: 0.01

%%equations
x = g/2 * t.^2 % distance

x1 = 1/2 * v^2/g % distance at v=-10m/s

dx = g * t % velocity 

%%plotting
clf
yyaxis left
plot (t,x)
hold on
xlabel('t [s]')
ylabel('x [m]')

yyaxis right
plot (t, dx)
hold on
xlabel('t [s]')
ylabel('dx [m/s]')
title('Trajectory of the fallen ball')

lgd = legend({'x(t)','v(t)'},'FontSize',12, 'location', 'NorthEast')

set(gca, 'Fontsize', 18)
grid on
```

**And here is my solution, which does not work properly right now:**

```
%% definitions
%# control animation speed
DELAY = 0.01
numPoints = 600;

% initial velocity is assumed to be zero
g = -9.81; % [m/s^2]
m = 1; % [kg]
v = -10; % velocity [m/s]
x = [0:10];

t = [0:0.01:2]; % Vector with 10 Elements, step size: 0.01

%%equations
x = g/2 * t.^2 % distance

x1 = 1/2 * v^2/g % distance at v=-10m/s

dx = g * t % velocity 

b = linspace(x1,10,numPoints); %ball --> way x

%%plotting
clf
figure('DoubleBuffer','on')
yyaxis left
plot (t,x)
hold on
xlabel('t [s]')
ylabel('x [m]')

yyaxis right
plot (t, dx)
hold on
xlabel('t [s]')
ylabel('dx [m/s]')
title('Trajectory of the fallen ball')

lgd = legend({'x(t)','v(t)'},'FontSize',12, 'location', 'NorthEast')

set(gca, 'Fontsize', 18)
grid on

%# create moving point # coords text
hLine = line('XData',t(1), 'YData',b(1), 'Color','r', ...
    'Marker','o', 'MarkerSize',6, 'LineWidth',2);
hTxt = text(t(1), ball(1), sprintf('(%.3f,%.3f)',t(1),b(1)), ...
    'Color',[0.2 0.2 0.2], 'FontSize',8, ...
    'HorizontalAlignment','left', 'VerticalAlignment','top');

%# infinite loop
i=1;
while true
    %# update point & text
    set(hLine, 'XData', t(i), 'YData',b(i))
    set(hTxt, 'Position', [t(i) ball(i)], ...
        'String', sprintf('%.3f,%3f)',[t(i) b(i)]))
    drawnow                                  %# force refresh
    %#pause(DELAY)                           %# slow down animation

    i = rem(i+1,numPoints)+1;                %# circular increment
    if ~ishandle(hLine), break; end          %# in case you close the figure
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687437/points-moving-along-a-curve-within-matlab?rq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959528/creating-a-point-moving-along-a-graph-in-matlab?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things unclear to me:

- According to your definition of `hLine` and `hText` the vector/array `b` should contain the y-values for the ball at the specific time points. Instead you define `b=linspace(x1,10,numPoints)`. That gives you specific time points.
- What is `ball`? It's used in the while-loop but nowhere defined.
- First you define `x=[0;10]` and a few lines later you redefine `x=g/2 * t.^2;`.

Assuming I understood your needs correctly, here's a way to do it:

```
%% definitions
%# control animation speed
DELAY = 0.01;
%numPoints = 600;

% initial velocity is assumed to be zero
g = -9.81;               % [m/s^2]
m = 1;                   % [kg]
v = -10;                 % velocity [m/s]
tball = [0:DELAY:2];     % Vector with 10 Elements, step size: 0.01
t = linspace(0, 2, 500); % for plotting the two curves 

%%equations
x = g/2 * t.^2;         % distance
x1 = 1/2 * v^2/g;       % distance at v=-10m/s
dx = g * t;             % velocity 
ball1 = g/2 * tball.^2; % Position of Ball 1
ball2 = g * tball;      % Position of Ball 2
%b = linspace(x1,10,numPoints); %ball --> way x

%%plotting
clf
figure('DoubleBuffer','on')
yyaxis left
plot (t,x)
hold on
xlabel('t [s]')
ylabel('x [m]')

yyaxis right
plot (t, dx)
hold on
xlabel('t [s]')
ylabel('dx [m/s]')
title('Trajectory of the fallen ball')

lgd = legend({'x(t)','v(t)'},'FontSize',12, 'location', 'NorthEast');

set(gca, 'Fontsize', 18)
grid on

% create moving point coords text for ball 1 and ball 2
hLine1 = line('XData',tball(1), 'YData',ball1(1), 'Color','r', ...
    'Marker','o', 'MarkerSize',6, 'LineWidth',2);
hTxt1 = text(tball(1), ball1(1), sprintf('(%.3f,%.3f)',tball(1),ball1(1)), ...
    'Color',[0.2 0.2 0.2], 'FontSize',8, ...
    'HorizontalAlignment','left', 'VerticalAlignment','top');
hLine2 = line('XData',tball(1), 'YData',ball2(1), 'Color','r', ...
    'Marker','o', 'MarkerSize',6, 'LineWidth',2);
hTxt2 = text(tball(1), ball2(1), sprintf('(%.3f,%.3f)',tball(1),ball2(1)), ...
    'Color',[0.2 0.2 0.2], 'FontSize',8, ...
    'HorizontalAlignment','left', 'VerticalAlignment','top');


i=1;
while true
    % update point & text for ball 1
    set(hLine1, 'XData', tball(i), 'YData',ball1(i))
    set(hTxt1, 'Position', [tball(i) ball1(i)], ...
        'String', sprintf('%.3f,%3f)',[tball(i) ball1(i)]))
    % ... and the same for ball 2
    set(hLine2, 'XData', tball(i), 'YData',ball2(i))
    set(hTxt2, 'Position', [tball(i) ball2(i)], ...
        'String', sprintf('%.3f,%3f)',[tball(i) ball2(i)]))
    drawnow                                  % force refresh
    %#pause(DELAY)                           % slow down animation

    % To stop the balls at t=1
    if tball(i) == 1
        %i = 1; continue;
        break;
    end

    i = rem(i+1,length(tball))+1;            % circular increment
    if ~ishandle(hLine1), break; end         % in case you close the figure
end
```

Comment: THIS IS AWESOME!!! :-D Thanks a lot! ;-) 
You are right, I had some unlogic in my code. Is it possible to let the balls stop at v = -10m/s (equals t=1)?

Comment: @ChristineHümmer Sure, you just need an if-statement in the while-loop, see my edited answer.  If you want the animation to start from the beginning after t=1, then just remove the `break` statement and uncomment the line `i=1; continue;` above.